# Base entity with concrete inheritance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

I want to have a base entity with a field `deleted` which marks a deleted record. And i have 2 subclasses, each of them to have their own table with all own columns:

```
from elixir import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


class Catalog(Entity):
    using_options(inheritance='concrete')
    deleted = Boolean

class Contact(Catalog):
    using_options(inheritance='concrete')
    name = Field(String(60))

class Location(Catalog):
    using_options(inheritance='concrete')
    name = Field(String(100))

setup_all()

metadata.bind = create_engine('sqlite:///', echo=True)
metadata.create_all()
```

And the result:

```
CREATE TABLE __main___catalog (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE __main___contact (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        name VARCHAR(60), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE __main___location (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        name VARCHAR(100), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Questions:

1. <s>How to avoid creation of a table for the base entity?</s> - solved: `using_options(abstract = True)`
2. <s>Why field `deleted` is not in the created tables?</s> - this solved - i forgot to put it inside a `Field`
3. I want to avoid typing in each subclass `using_options(inheritance='concrete')` but still have "concrete inheritance". Is there a way to make it default for all subclasses?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
class Catalog(Entity):

    deleted = Field(Boolean)
    using_options(abstract = True, inheritance = 'concrete')        


class Contact(Catalog):

    name = Field(String(60))


class Location(Catalog):

    name = Field(String(100))
```

and creates the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE __main___contact (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        deleted BOOLEAN, 
        name VARCHAR(60), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id), 
        CHECK (deleted IN (0, 1))
)

CREATE TABLE __main___location (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        deleted BOOLEAN, 
        name VARCHAR(100), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id), 
        CHECK (deleted IN (0, 1))
)
```